# Can you have two instances of a model in one test function in phpunit?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to test that a duplicate user cannot be inserted.  To do this, I am creating 2 user objects with the same details, just changing account name - since this is something that is also unique.

However, my setter doesn't seem to be setting the company name second time around.  When I echo from the model, the property I am trying to set is still the same from the previous object I created.  My test fails as it throws the account already exists exception I set up

`Failed asserting that exception of type "Models\AccountAlreadyExistsException" matches expected exception "Models\UserAlreadyExistsException".`

```
public function testCantInsertDuplicateUser ()
{

    $user = new \Models\User();
    $user->first_name = 'John';
    $user->surname = 'Smith';
    $user->email = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $user->password = 'password';
    $user->password_confirmation = 'password';
    $user->setCompanyName('Star');
    $user->setPackageId(2);
    $this->assertTrue($user->signUp());

    $user2 = new \Models\User();
    $user2->first_name = 'John';
    $user2->surname = 'Smith';
    $user2->email = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $user2->password = 'password';
    $user2->password_confirmation = 'password';
    $user2->setCompanyName('cross');
    $user2->setPackageId(2);

    $this->setExpectedException('Models\UserAlreadyExistsException');
    $user2->signUp();
}

//user model
    public function setCompanyName ($company_name)
{
    $this->company_name = $company_name;
}

private function insertAccount ()
{
    $account = new \Models\Account;


    $account->setCompanyName($this->company_name);

    $account->setPackageId($this->package_id);

    $this->account_message_bag = new \Illuminate\Support\MessageBag();

    if (!$account->insert()) {

        $this->account_message_bag = $account->getValidationErrors();

    }

    return $account;
}

private function insertUser ()
{
    $save_user = $this->save(self::$rules, array(), array(), function ($model)
    {
        //this is all performed before save
        $existing_email = User::where('email', "=", $this->email)->count();

        if ($existing_email) {

            //delete account that was created in previous step
            //as the signup hasn't been successful

            $this->account->delete();

            throw new UserAlreadyExistsException();

        }

        //are there any account validation errors?

        if (count($this->account_message_bag->getMessages()>0)) {

            return false;
        }

    });

    return $save_user;
}

public function signUp ()
{
    $this->account = $this->insertAccount();

    $this->account_id = $this->account->getId();


    if (!$this->insertUser()) {

        //delete the company created in previous step

        $this->account->delete();

        $user_message_bag = Ardent::errors();

        //combine user and account validation eerrors

        $message_array = array_merge($user_message_bag->getMessages(), $this->account_message_bag->getMessages());

        $this->validation_errors = new \Illuminate\Support\MessageBag($message_array);

        throw new GenericValidationException();
    }

    //TODO - does this return false on failure?

    $sent = $this->sendConfirmEmail();

    if (!$sent) {

        throw new WelcomeEmailNotSent();
    }
    //sende confirm email
    return true;
}

//Account model

public function insert ()
{
    $result = $this->save(self::$rules, array(), array(), function()
    {
        $existing_company_name = \Models\Account::where('company_name', '=', $this->company_name)->count();

        if ($existing_company_name) {
            throw new AccountAlreadyExistsException();
        }
    });

    if (!$result) {


        $this->validation_errors = Ardent::errors();

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the point in having the `setCompanyName` function? You can set it just the same using the property. Or if it's meant to be a mutator then it needs to be named `setCompanyNameAttribute` otherwise Laravel won't pick it up. Also if you are setting the attribute internally I believe you need to use `$this->attributes['company_name'] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

check the way you validate the AccountAlreadyExistsException

may be you should change the email

Comment: no the point is the email is the same, so it throws an exception saying so, but it's not getting past the Account already exists, and from testing my code by echoing as it's running the tests, user2's company name is not being set, it's got the company name from $user.

Answer (score 0):

Your namespaces are likely the problem.

You create the class in \Models, but use Models (without the backslash) for the exception.  Maybe your code is throwing \Models\UserAlreadyExsitsException, not Models\UserAlreadyExistsException.

```
$user2 = new \Models\User();
...
$this->setExpectedException('Models\UserAlreadyExistsException');
```

Maybe this should be '\Models\UserAlreadyExistsException'

```
$user2 = new \Models\User();
...
$this->setExpectedException('\Models\UserAlreadyExistsException');
```

Comment: I tried changing that.  It still throws the same account exists error.  It's just that when setting up $user2, I don't know how it has got the company name of $user.  I do an echo in the signUp() function showing the company name and both times it runs, it has the same company_name.  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I would suggest trying this in the debugger, and ensure you do have two distinct objects created. Also, ensure you are not using self:: inside the classes to set values, since they would go to the base class that both are.  Maybe post the code for the class to help?

Comment: Well you got me there.  Instead of calling $user2->setCompanyName() I did $user->company_name = 'cross' and that seemed to work ok.  I don't get why though.  It works using setCompanyName() the first time.

Comment: @Nicola I can only assume it is how you are doing the settings in the code itself, without seeing the actual class posted.

Comment: I've edited my code to show the setter.  It's not a static setter.

Comment: Maybe paste the base class, variable definition.  I do not see anything that would cause the problem you are describing.

Comment: You have some self:: references. This tends to be the main object, not your instance of the object, however it does not appear to be a problem here, since you are referencing Rules which I assume will be constant in the class.  Can you post the small example class with the variables, etc... (or a snippet in the various web tools) or maybe shrink to a very simple class to attempt to show the problem.  Sometimes, this compression will help illustrate the problem to you as well.